# POST jersey with HeaderParam annotation

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey

I get null when I send a POST. Please someone know how to pass value with Angular using `@HeaderParam` in Jersey?

I have this in backend:

```
 @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Users loginUser(@HeaderParam("username")String username,@HeaderParam("password") String password){
        System.out.println("What happen"+userService.loginService(username, password));
       return userService.loginService(username, password);
    }
```

and this in front-end, using Angular:

```
 $scope.getUserFunction = function () {
      $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'http://localhost:8080/JersyBackEnd/resources/login'+data,
        contentType:'application/json',
        data    : {username: "akram",password:"yes"},
      })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    };
```

I get 204 because of the null data.
Can anyone help me, either using HeaderParam, PathParam or FormParm annotations in Jersey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is sent as the request body. What you really want is `headers`.
[From the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> - **data** – `{string|Object}` – Data to be sent as the request message data.
> - **headers** – `{Object}` – Map of strings or functions which return strings representing HTTP headers to send to the server. If the return value of a function is null, the header will not be sent. Functions accept a config object as an argument.

Example:

```
$http({
  ...
  headers: {
    username: "akram",
    password: "yes"
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi @gustavohenke i get this error Request header field username is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: So you have another problem here: You'll need to enable CORS in your server.

Comment: i did but the same error , je ne sais pas ce que signifie cette erreur  username is not allowed

Comment: what is the best send data  with HeaderParam or FormParam

Comment: As always, *it depends*. You're trying to send authentication data, which is better suited to headers IMHO; otherwise, go with request bodies.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@HeaderParam`, you have to pass the values from .JS using  `headers: { 'something': 'anything' }`. As i can see currently you are using `data    : {username: "akram",password:"yes"}`. try to use `headers: { 'something': 'anything' }` instead of this.

Please try header, hope it will solve your null issue.